# Regard to the technical definition of a Mott insulator

Tags: condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, superconductivity, strong-correlated

I was reading Chapter 16 of the textbook on [advanced solid state physics by Philip Phillips](https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/advanced-solid-state-physics/4A95C82854C0AA277D785E4D47699511). In this chapter, the physics of Mottness is comprehensively discussed. There is a statement he made on page 364 (chap 16.3) about the definition of Mott insulator:

> The technical definition of a Mott insulator is: any partially filled band for which the corresponding retarded Green function in the *paramagnetic* state has a *vanishing real part* at some value of chemical potential along a connected surface in momentum space.

I understand the fact that when the real part of the retarded Green function is zero, it means that electrons are not the propagating degrees of freedom.
In the textbook above this statement, he gives a calculation of the atomic limit of 2D Hubbard model and shows that retarded Green function at *zero frequency* indeed vanishes.

Here my question is: what should be the **frequency** of the retarded Green function in the definition above, should it be zero or any other value?

Comment: To vanish the real part of the Green's function is a sufficient condition, isn't it ?

Comment: @FraSchelle Yes, I think so.

Comment: I mean, the frequency is fixed by the condition of the vanishing of the real part of the Green's function... Am I clear ?

Comment: @FraSchelle I see, but won't this be too arbitrary? I mean, if the frequency is not fixed at the beginning, how can one predict the chemical potential (zero-surface)? Also, could the frequency $\omega$ be different on the zero-surface?